# Upgrading GMP to 5.0.5

Tags: make

I tried building GMP 5.0.5, and now when I'm trying to build MPFR, it starts checking for gmp.h and libgmp. The MPFR gives me an error that `gmp.h (5.0.5) and libgmp (5.0.2) do not match`, and MPFR is giving me the above error during `make` when it reaches to the gmp stage. how can I fix this problem? 
Also, is there a way to check if gmp, mpfr or mpc are pre-existing on my machine, and their version numbers?

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same problem. I found out that my *gcc-4.6.3* somewhat miscompiles it. After upgrading to gcc-4.7 and recompiling *gmp-5.0.5*, I was able to install *mpfr-3.1.1* smoothly (`make check` passes).